# Count specific values in a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series in python.
Is there a function/easy way to construct a series which contains the number of appearances of given values?

For demonstration, suppose I have the following Series: `1, 3, 1, 5, 10`.
I want to count how many appearances each value has, from the following list: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`.
The series that should return is `2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do `value_counts` + `reindex`

```
l=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
l1=[1, 3, 1, 5, 10]
pd.Series(l1).value_counts().reindex(l,fill_value=0).tolist()
[2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `numpy.bincount`

```
import numpy as np
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
s = pd.Series([1, 3, 1, 5, 10])

out = list(np.bincount(s)[[l]])
out
[2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

With map:

```
s = pd.Series([1, 3, 1, 5, 10])
inp_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

pd.Series(inp_list).map(s.value_counts()).fillna(0).astype(int).tolist()
```

Or list comp with `get`

```
c = s.value_counts()
[c.get(i,0) for i in inp_list]
#or [*map(lambda x: c.get(x,0),inp_list)]
```

---

```
[2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```